# Accessing Individual leaf in leaf in list of yang

Tags: rest, opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-restconf

I want to access value of leaf of list in yang module?
Ex

```
       module abc
       {
       list xyz{
       key a;
       leaf a{
           type int
       },
       leaf b{
           type string
       },
       leaf c{
           type string
       },
       leaf d{
           type string
       }
       }
       }
```

REST should be like "abc/xyz/(which is key)" i.e. (abc/xyz/1)

it will give all values of a,b,c,d.

But if I want to access of individual element b,c,d individual which is non key.
How can we write REST API?

Comment: Have you tried `GET https://my-host.org/restconf/data/abc:xyz=my-key/b`?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in [RFC8040, Section 3.5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8040#section-3.5.3). Here's the example from this section:

> Examples:

> ```
>  container top {
> ```

```
      list list1 {
          key "key1 key2 key3";
           ...
           list list2 {
               key "key4 key5";
               ...
               leaf X { type string; }
           }
       }
       leaf-list Y {
         type uint32;
       }
   }
```

> For the above YANG definition, the container "top" is defined in the
> "example-top" YANG module, and a target resource URI for leaf "X"
> would be encoded as follows:

> ```
>   /restconf/data/example-top:top/list1=key1,key2,key3/\
> ```

```
      list2=key4,key5/X
```

> For the above YANG definition, a target resource URI for
> leaf-list "Y" would be encoded as follows:

> ```
>   /restconf/data/example-top:top/Y=instance-value
> ```

> The following example shows how reserved characters are
> percent-encoded within a key value.  The value of "key1" contains
> a comma, single-quote, double-quote, colon, double-quote, space,
> and forward slash (,'":" /).  Note that double-quote is not a
> reserved character and does not need to be percent-encoded.  The
> value of "key2" is the empty string, and the value of "key3" is the
> string "foo".

> Example URL:

> ```
>  /restconf/data/example-top:top/list1=%2C%27"%3A"%20%2F,,foo
> ```

So in the context of your example, you would do `/restconf/data/abc:xyz=my-key/b`, `/restconf/data/abc:xyz=my-key/c` or `/restconf/data/abc:xyz=my-key/d`, where ***my-key*** is the key of the list instance's entry you wish to query.

Comment: augment "aug:aug1"{
 container top {
      list list1 {
          key "key1 key2 key3";
           ...
           list list2 {
               key "key4 key5";
               ...
               leaf X { type string; }
           }
       }
       leaf-list Y {
         type uint32;
       }
   }
   }

If I have this type of yang snip, please guide me accordingly.

Comment: @TapanDave, the only thing that changes with augmentation is the module name prefix (eg. `example-top:` or `abc:` above) for nodes that are from another module.